# Vertical Align (line-height method) not working

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

My code in my HTML file is as follows:

```css
#firstblock h1 {
    font-family:'Open Sans';
    font-size: 12vh;
    text-align: center;
}
#firstblock {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="firstblock">
  <div id="title">
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I see no reason why the vertical align is not working. I would appreciate any help, but I would rather not use the table method. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close.  Set the margins to 0 on `h1` and you will get the expected result.

```css
#firstblock {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
#firstblock h1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 12vh;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="firstblock">
  <div id="title">
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that has not worked. I copied and pasted your exact code into my web page and it is exactly the same. I have no other code on the page besides my head, body and html tags.

Comment: The issue is that I want to center it vertically on the whole page. When I change the '200px' to '100%' it stops working.

Comment: Sorted by using 'vh' instead of %. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I view the code it is vertical aligning the heading. Do you have a line-height already set on the H1 in an earlier instance in your code? You may have to set the line-height on the H1 instead of the wrapping div. The only other way is to:

```
#firstblock {display: table;}
#firstblock h1 {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle}
```

Comment: Neither of your methods worked. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: I tried setting the line-height on the h1, and also the table method. The table method simply placed in the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

ok try this. Add width 100% to #firstblock and instead of vertical-aligning the h1 we're going to style the parent div.

```
#firstblock {display: table; width: 100%;}
#firstblock #title {
   display: table-cell;
   height: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Unfortunately to vertical align it on the whole page using 100% all parent elements have to have a height of 100%. So try applying a height of 100% to all parent elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  #firstblock {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}

 #firstblock h1  {
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 font-size: 12vh;
 text-align: center;
 border: solid 5px #acecaa;
 margin:50% 0% 50% 0%;
 }
```